# MemoryStream not writing data from datatable

Tags: c#, excel, memorystream, xssf

I have datatable that I'm populating with data and passing through to a method which is supposed to write the data to a memory stream and save it as an Excel spreadsheet. The datatable is correctly populated, but when the memorystream writes it, the capacity of the memorystream is 0. It's as though it just doesn't write anything. Could this be caused by some sort of memory leak? Below is my code that I use to write the workbook (populated by the datatable) using the memorystream

```
    public static MemoryStream Grid_Export_Excel(DataTable data)
    {
        try
        {
            var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();
            var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

            // Set the column names in the header row
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
                headerRow.CreateCell(i).SetCellValue(data.Columns[i].ColumnName);

            // Freeze the header row so that it's not scrolled
            sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

            for (int r = 0; r < data.Rows.Count; r++)
            {
                // Create a new row
                var row = sheet.CreateRow(r + 1);

                // Get the DataRow
                var dataRow = data.Rows[r];

                for (int c = 0; c < data.Columns.Count; c++)
                {
                    // Get the fieldname
                    var fieldname = data.Columns[c].ColumnName;

                    // Make sure that the field exists in the datarow
                    if (!dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(fieldname))
                        continue;

                    // Create the cell in the row
                    row.CreateCell(c).SetCellValue(dataRow[fieldname].ToString());
                }
            }

            // Write the workbook to a stream and return as FileStreamResult
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            workbook.Write(ms);
            return ms;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing something in the _workbook.Write_ line? Where is supposed to write to?

Comment: Memoryleaks do not lose data but memory space. How do you connect the stream with your data?? Try `workbook.Write(ms);`

Comment: You are not writing to the memory stream at all, which is why it contains no data.

Comment: maybe ms.Flush() ?

Comment: Apologies - I have updated my code. I am writing to the memorystream (workbook.Write(ms))
Where should I place ms.flush()?

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }` is totally *useless*, drop it

Comment: `MemoryStream.Flush()` [does not actually do anything](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,996367c59ff4f5de) so calling it isn't going to help. Your problem would appear to be an issue with  `workbook.Write()` rather than anything to do with not flushing the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: I seemed to have figured out the problem. There is apparently dependancy between NPOI nuget packages and SharpZipLib. SharpZipLib was using an older version while NPOI a later. This is what caused the data not to be pulled through and written